# How to fix AR connected issue in my device?

Tags: android, google-play-services, version, augmented-reality, arcore

I am developing a website related to Augmented Reality. But my mobile phone (Samsung Galaxy M02S) is not supported AR. When I try to install ARcore, google play store show an error.
[image: an error which was show google play store]

So I installed ARcore using apk and now this app was installed. After that, I checked my mobile phone AR was supported or not. The below notification was shown when I try to see AR.

[image: After installed ARcore using apk]

How I fix this issue and have any other way to install ARcore into my phone?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AR Core requires some specific hardware to work. You can check the list of supported devices [here](https://developers.google.com/ar/devices). No amount of side loading will help because this is a hardware requirement issue. Moreover AR Core is under active development even if you somehow install a version that might work that version will soon be deprecated and you will start getting the popup saying you need to update.

Kindly use a device that is part of supported list or an Emulator that supports this. IMHO it is best to develop using a device that has support from AR Core team.

Comment: Can you tell ssuitable emulator for this @TaranmeetSingh

Comment: @NirodhaLakmali You can find exact specifications here https://developers.google.com/ar/devices#emulators .